# Is it possible to use the Chrome API within a content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am currently trying to download a file through a content script. However, it appears to be doing nothing. I have also tried to send a message to my background script and then download it from the background file, however it appears no message  was received.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(message == "handle_all") {
        let is_playing = document.getElementsByClassName("playControl")[0].innerHTML == "Pause current";
        let volume = document.getElementsByClassName("volume__sliderWrapper")[0].getAttribute('aria-valuenow');

        SC.initialize({
            client_id: 'censored',
        });

        if(is_playing) {
            SC.resolve('https://soundcloud.com/moow-beatmaker/it-wasnt-me').then(function(track) {
                chrome.downloads.download({
                    url: "track.download_url + '?client_id=censored'",
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Nothing happens. No download, nothing. When I visit the download page myself I get error code 406 'Not Acceptable'.

Is this an issue with not being able to use the Chrome API within a content script or is there an issue with the API I am downloading the file from?

Comment: Content scripts can't use chrome.downloads API. Messaging to the background script is the only solution so - can you add your code that didn't work and manifest.json to the question?

Comment: @wOxxOm I was able to send a message to the background script, however now I get an invalid URL error when downloading. However, the URL seems completely valid to me: "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/269174566/download?client_id=censored". Does chrome need an exact file with an extension?

Comment: I need to look at the real code.